# JS Function Wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following two code examples:

```
// Example 1
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    alert('I was clicked');
});

// Example 2
$('#myButton').click(
    alert('I was clicked');
);
```

Why specifically does example 2 not work?

Comment: Because one passes a reference to a function and the other passes the **result** of invoking the alert function.  jQuery.click() expects a function reference as its argument, which it refers to as a _handler_ in the [API documnentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: @jahroy Looking at the docs I see .click( handler(eventObject) ) I've always been confused by the different syntax used in representing arguments. It seems like each language or person wants to do this differently.

Comment: Yep, documentation is not quite as consistent for JavaScript/jQuery as it is for Java and C#... I think it's a lot easier when the language is strongly typed!  Notice the comment next to the _handler_ argument: "_A function to execute each time the event is triggered._"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second code snippet does not work because it invokes the [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert) method of the `window` object (which returns `undefined`), and passes *the value it returns* (thus, `undefined`) as a handler to the [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method of a jQuery object.

`undefined` is not a valid event handler, so `click()` ignores it and does nothing (except maybe log an error to your console, depending on your browser).

Your first code snippet passes a genuine function that, in turn, invokes `alert()`. Since it is a function, it can be registered as an event handler.